# Draw a line in tradingview using pine script

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading

I want to draw a line using pinescript from price 6920 to 6800 in trading view chart. For that I tried:

```
line.new(0, y1 = 6920,  y2 = 6800, extend=extend.right)
```

It shows me an error:-

> Cannot call 'line.new' with arguments (literal integer, y1=literal
> integer, y2=literal integer, extend=const string); available
> overloads: line.new(series[integer], series[float], series[integer],
> series[float], series[string], series[string], series[color],
> series[string], series[integer]) => series[line]

Answer (score 0):

You to pass x1 as integer, y1 as float

```
y1 = float(6920.00)
y2 = float(6800.00)
line.new(0, y1,  0, y2, extend=extend.right)
```